# how to flat array js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js

How to flatten this array :

```js
[
  {ID: 0 , TITLE: 'A', children: [{ID: 1, TITLE: 'AA'}]},
  {ID: 2 , TITLE: 'B', children: []},
  {ID: 3 , TITLE: 'C', children: [{ID: 4, TITLE: 'CC', children:[{ID: 5, TITLE: 'CCC'}]}]}
]
```

To get something like this :

- A
- A / AA
- B
- C / CC / CCC

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: `to get sth like this` what should that be???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to complicate things here, you just need a function that loop over the array items, get their `TITLE` and if the item has `children`, we call the function recursively:

```
function getLevels(array, parent) {
  var results = [];
  array.forEach(function(el) {
    results.push(!parent ? el["TITLE"] : parent + "/" + el["TITLE"]);
    let prefix = parent ? parent + "/" + el["TITLE"] : el["TITLE"];
    if (el.children && el.children.length > 0) {
      getLevels(el.children, prefix).forEach(function(child) {
        results.push(child);
      });
    }
  });
  return results;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [{
    ID: 0,
    TITLE: 'A',
    children: [{
      ID: 1,
      TITLE: 'AA'
    }]
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    TITLE: 'B',
    children: []
  },
  {
    ID: 3,
    TITLE: 'C',
    children: [{
      ID: 4,
      TITLE: 'CC',
      children: [{
        ID: 5,
        TITLE: 'CCC'
      }]
    }]
  }
];

function getLevels(array, parent) {
  var results = [];
  array.forEach(function(el) {
    results.push(!parent ? el["TITLE"] : parent + "/" + el["TITLE"]);
    let prefix = parent ? parent + "/" + el["TITLE"] : el["TITLE"];
    if (el.children && el.children.length > 0) {
      getLevels(el.children, prefix).forEach(function(child) {
        results.push(child);
      });
    }
  });
  return results;
}

console.log(getLevels(arr));
```

### Edit:

This is how to proceed to get the `id` in the array:

```
results.push({
  "ID": el["ID"],
  "TITLE": (!parent ? el["TITLE"] : parent + "/" + el["TITLE"])
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [{
    ID: 0,
    TITLE: 'A',
    children: [{
      ID: 1,
      TITLE: 'AA'
    }]
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    TITLE: 'B',
    children: []
  },
  {
    ID: 3,
    TITLE: 'C',
    children: [{
      ID: 4,
      TITLE: 'CC',
      children: [{
        ID: 5,
        TITLE: 'CCC'
      }]
    }]
  }
];

function getLevels(array, parent) {
  var results = [];
  array.forEach(function(el) {
    results.push({
      "ID": el["ID"],
      "TITLE": (!parent ? el["TITLE"] : parent + "/" + el["TITLE"])
    });
    let prefix = parent ? parent + "/" + el["TITLE"] : el["TITLE"];
    if (el.children && el.children.length > 0) {
      getLevels(el.children, prefix).forEach(function(child) {
        results.push(child);
      });
    }
  });
  return results;
}

console.log(getLevels(arr));
```

Comment: I want a result like this :  A , A/AA, B, C, C/CC, C/CC/CCC

Comment: @DeGiovanni I edited the answer and now, it fits exactly your desired output.

Comment: @chsdk how could i add the id corresponding to each item in the array? have a result like this exemple : [{ID : 0 , TITLE: A}, {ID : 1 , TITLE: A / AA}, {ID : 2 , TITLE: B}, {ID : 3 , TITLE: C}, {ID : 4 , TITLE: C / CC}, {ID : 5 , TITLE: C / CC / CCC}].

Comment: @chsdk Thanks, because I need get the id of each item too. Thank youuuu

Comment: @DeGiovanni You are welcome, glad it helps. It's all about how to handle your array and its objects. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use store the nested item of the actual object and take an iterative and recursive approach with a closure over the path.

For an incrementing `ID`, you could use either an additional variable for incrementing if a new row is found or iterate at the end the given array and add the index as `id`.

This proposal uses an additional `id` variable, because it requires no extra loop.

```js
var array = [{ ID: 0, TITLE: 'A', children: [{ ID: 1, TITLE: 'AA' }] }, { ID: 2, TITLE: 'B', children: [] }, { ID: 3, TITLE: 'C', children: [{ ID: 4, TITLE: 'CC', children: [{ ID: 5, TITLE: 'CCC' }] }] }],
    id = 0,
    result = array.reduce(function f(p) {
        return function (r, o) {
            var temp = p.concat(o.TITLE);
            r.push({ ID: id++, TITLE: temp.join('/') });
            if (o.children) {
                o.children.reduce(f(temp), r);
            }
            return r;
        };
    }([]), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is the best solution for me. gj Nina

Comment: Actually, this is not what the OP is looking for, you jhave just separated the `children` from their `parents`.

Comment: @chsdk, actually op has not given a wanted result. it looks like a flat one, but with `A` it looks strange.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes it's flat, but the OP has another desired output.

Comment: If you don't know what the OP's desired result is, why answer? Also, please encourage the OP to show effort instead of just spoonfeeding the answer.

Comment: No I want a result like this :  A , A/AA, B, C, C/CC, C/CC/CCC

Comment: @DeGiovanni, please add this information to the question **and** your code as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz how could i add the id corresponding to each item in the array? have a result like this exemple : [{ID : 0 , TITLE: A}, {ID : 1 , TITLE: A / AA}, {ID : 2 , TITLE: B}, {ID : 3 , TITLE: C}, {ID : 4 , TITLE: C / CC}, {ID : 5 , TITLE: C / CC / CCC}].

Answer (score 0):

Did you want something like this?

```
function merge(input, flat_array) {
  if (!flat_array) {
    // this is the initial recursive call, make the input
    // (an array) have the same { child:[] } structure
    // as children calls will end up having
    flat_array = [];
    input = { children: input };
  } else {
    // since the parent call is just a plain array it doesnt
    // have a title so dont bother inserting anything
    flat_array.push(input.TITLE);
  }
  for (let i in input.children) {
    // recursively merge the children in into the flat array
    // too
    merge(input.children[i], flat_array);
  }
  return flat_array;
}

merge(x);
```

produces:

```
["A", "AA", "B", "C", "CC", "CCC"]
```

Comment: Actually, this is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: No I want a result like this :  A , A/AA, B, C, C/CC, C/CC/CCC

Comment: @DeGiovanni, do you need arrays, objects, string(s)... as output? And yes, change your question too: you need to show levels, right?